# Mysql count number of regex match per field

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm trying to get mysql return the number of times a regex matches.

something like:

```
select 'aabbccaa' regexp 'a'
```

should return 4 (4 matches of a), rather than just true (or 1).

any way around it???

thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a function:

```
delimiter ||
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS substrCount||
CREATE FUNCTION substrCount(s VARCHAR(255), ss VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED LANGUAGE SQL NOT DETERMINISTIC READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
DECLARE count TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED;
DECLARE offset TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET s = NULL;

SET count = 0;
SET offset = 1;

REPEAT
IF NOT ISNULL(s) AND offset > 0 THEN
SET offset = LOCATE(ss, s, offset);
IF offset > 0 THEN
SET count = count + 1;
SET offset = offset + 1;
END IF;
END IF;
UNTIL ISNULL(s) OR offset = 0 END REPEAT;

RETURN count;
END;

||
delimiter ;
```

Which you can call then like this

```
SELECT substrCount('aabbccaa', 'a') `count`;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like 'a' was just a test, and future ones would actually need to work with legitimate regular expressions

Comment: Then it would be good to know, what the RegExp should look like. Maybe one can put its logic to this function using Locate()

Answer (score 1):

I think that there is no regex engine that will do this. Regular expressions can't count. Of course, most regex dialects have some sort of `findall()` method, and you can then count the number of matches yourself.

MySQL, however, doesn't have this functionality. The LOCATE function only takes strings, not regexes - otherwise you could have worked with that.

Comment: The need for the the count of matches, is because I wanted to ORDER BY it - and get the top 5 lines that matched most of the times.
Maybe a mysql User Defined Funtion would do it?

Comment: I understand your problem, but I don't know MySQL well enough to make a suggestion for a workaround, sorry.