# I want to use like key words in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql db and and i have a table called INFO it has a column INFO_NUMBER and INFO_SUBJECT and it contains string as

```
+--------------+-------------------------+
| INFO_NUMBER | INFO_SUBJECT           |
+--------------+-------------------------+
| A3L1         | updated                 |
| A3L2         | updated updated         |
| A3L3         | updated updated updated |
+--------------+-------------------------+
```

and now i want to fetch only those record whose INFO_SUBJECT contains maximum of updated string through like keyword and i don't know how many times updated string should be appended

this is becoz of searching and my requirement is same.

my query is :
SELECT INFO_NUMBER,INFO_SUBJECT FROM INFO WHERE INFO_SUBJECT LIKE "UP%";
but it returns all the records.

Thanks

Comment: 'INFO_SUBJECT contains maximum of updated string' what does this mean? My guess is you will need String functions. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html

Comment: Of course LIKE "UP%" is going to return all the results because all your values being with up.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if this can be done with a single query (even if possible, there might be performance implications). But this might help [Mysql count number of regex match per field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144214/mysql-count-number-of-regex-match-per-field)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your data this will work:

```
SELECT * FROM INFO where length(INFO_SUBJECT) in (select max(length(INFO_SUBJECT)) from INFO);
```

More time updated word is in string more its length.

Comment: Hey Harry Thanks for reply                                          but, suppose INFO_SUBJECT column contain any string which is not started with key words that i want to specify for my search criteria then also it should be fetch but my requirement says it depends on my specify words not depends on length.

Comment: I know that situation that's why I stated in my answer:Based on your data in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM  INFO 
WHERE INFO_SUBJECT LIKE 'up%' 
AND length(INFO_SUBJECT) IN (SELECT MAX(length(INFO_SUBJECT)) FROM INFO);
```

Credit goes to  Harry Joy. He has already has answered your question. Small string I added with your permission Harry.

Comment: that won't work if there is an `INFO_SUBJECT` "pub pub pub pub pub pub" and the longest "updated" `INFO_SUBJECT` has only one entry, because the longest INFO_SUBJECT is not the one starting "up"