# MySQL: Return a number of matches

Tags: mysql

I'm building a search system in PHP and MySQL, and I've been requested something interesting. So, let's say I have a hypothetic table `results` (in my system, by the way, it's a view)...

```
id    text
1     "foo"
2     "foo bar"
3     "foo man choo"
4     "bar choo"
```

... and a very comprehensible `SELECT` query:

```
SELECT r.id, r.text
    FROM results AS r
    WHERE r.text REGEXP 'foo|bar|choo'
    AND r.text NOT REGEXP 'man'
```

Is there such a way, even if it means swapping that `REGEXP` by `LIKE`, that I can return, alongside this text an integer column that returns the number of matches in each line's `text`, so I can order this query by relevance/number of matches, so the result table looks like this?:

```
id    text          matches
2     "foo bar"     2
4     "bar choo"    2
1     "foo"         1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144214/mysql-count-number-of-regex-match-per-field

Comment: Would "choo choo foo bar" return 3 or 4?

Comment: That would be 3. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding the values together:

```
SELECT r.id, 
       r.text, 
       ((r.text REGEXP 'foo') +
        (r.text REGEXP 'bar') +
        (r.text REGEXP 'choo')
       ) as matches 
FROM results AS r
WHERE r.text REGEXP 'foo|bar|choo'
AND r.text NOT REGEXP 'man'
```

Comparisons (in MySQL) evaluate to either 0 (false) or 1, and you can add them together.

Comment: Confusingly similar to another answer posted some 4 minutes before :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like

```
SELECT r.id, 
       r.text, 
       r.text REGEXP 'foo' as foo, 
       r.text REGEXP 'bar' as bar,
       r.text REGEXP 'choo' as choo,
       (foo + bar + choo) as number_found 
FROM results AS r
WHERE r.text REGEXP 'foo|bar|choo'
AND r.text NOT REGEXP 'man'
```

However, this does not return the *number* of matches for a given pattern, just the number of patterns matches.