# MySQL Query Issue of appearance

Tags: mysql

This is my query, what I actually wants is to make search result order by most frequently appear word, and also word could me more than one, it is working on single word but when input more than one it ruin.

```
SELECT *,
       (LENGTH(`product_name`) - LENGTH(REPLACE(`product_name`, 'apple', ''))) /
       LENGTH('apple') + (LENGTH(`product_name`) - LENGTH(REPLACE(`product_name`, 
       'iphone', ''))) / LENGTH('iphone') + (LENGTH(`product_s_desc`) -     
       LENGTH(REPLACE(`product_s_desc`, 'apple', ''))) / LENGTH('apple') + 
       (LENGTH(`product_s_desc`) - LENGTH(REPLACE(`product_s_desc`, 'iphone',
       ''))) / 
       LENGTH('iphone') + (LENGTH(`product_sku`) - LENGTH(REPLACE(`product_sku`, 
       'apple', ''))) / LENGTH('apple') + (LENGTH(`product_sku`) - 
       LENGTH(REPLACE(`product_sku`, 'iphone', ''))) / LENGTH('iphone') 
       `occurences` 
FROM  `#__virtuemart_products` p, `#__virtuemart_products_".$dblangcode."` l 
WHERE (product_name LIKE '%apple%' OR product_name LIKE '%iphone%' AND 
       product_s_desc LIKE '%apple%' OR product_s_desc LIKE '%iphone%' AND 
       product_sku LIKE '%apple%' OR product_sku LIKE '%iphone%' ) 
ORDER BY `occurences` DESC
```

Comment: *by most frequently appear word* you mean that `apple` could be 5 times in `product_s_desc` ? so if we have `apple` in description 5 times it is more valued than 3 ? give me please example of raw data, and expected result of query?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bc9041/3

Comment: yup sir you are right this is what we wants

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql count number of regex match per field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144214/mysql-count-number-of-regex-match-per-field)

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6db49/3

Comment: the query is write is working here but not working in my server