# count from single column with multiple value

Tags: mysql

I have a table value like below,

```
id tank_id filledTime
1   TIND10 6PM,7PM,9PM,9PM,7PM,11PM,7PM,9PM,7PM,7PM,8PM,7PM,10PM,8PM,7PM,8PM,8PM,6PM,8PM,9PM,8PM,11PM,8PM
```

Expecting output :

```
tank_id NoOfTimeFilledInSpecTime
TIND10  2(6PM),7(7PM),4(9PM),2(11PM),7(8PM),1(10PM)
```

**Note** : `filledTime` is single column

How to achieve this using mysql query?

Comment: Normalize your data!

Comment: Don't you think that do it with program language will be easier?

Answer (score 0):

Is this select something to work on?

```
select tank_id, count(filledTime), filledTime
from yourtable
where filledTimein (select filledTimefrom yourtable)
and tank_id = 'TIND10'
group by tank_id,filledTime;
```

should be outputting this:

tank_id | count | filledtime
TIND10  | 2     | 6pm

and so on...

Comment: your query out put is : TIND10 1 '9PM,7PM,11PM,7PM,9PM,7PM,7PM,8PM,7PM,10PM,8PM,7PM,8PM,8PM,6PM,8PM,9PM,8PM,11PM,8PM,6PM,7PM,9PM' but please check my expecting output in question

Comment: My fault, I thought this PM stuff is in separate fields. So you have these PM values in one field and need to regex + count the values. Am I on the right way now? Damn... didnt see the note. Sorry again

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3241157/4927833 maybe you can use this function and concatinate it within your select clause

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your database is tankDetails and the table is tank. Then you can have a query like:

```
use tankDetails;
select tank_id,filledTime, count(filledTime) as NoofTime
from  tank
group by tank_id,filledTime;
```

Hope this helps!